# Given any arc, a radius and angle from centerpoint of circle, find offset point from centerpoint of circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

I'm working on a project in Adobe Illustrator where I am creating variable names on an arc of a fixed circle (radius = 22mm). The centerpoint on the arc will always be at 335 degrees of the circle. My dilemma is that I need to place each name into my printing software such that the centerpoint of the text is always in the same position. Basically, given the height and width of the name, and knowing the radius and 335 degree angle arc, I need to find how offset the intersecting point of the text frame is from the centerpoint of the circle so that I can move the image based on that offset. Here is a drawing showing the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Boe8Z.png

Here is another drawing [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQKTC.png) that illustrates the issue. The left artboard is the full potential area, illustrated as magenta in subsequent artboards. The area that I will know (w X h) are the green boxes for various potential name lengths on the curve. I need to move the green rectangle to the correct position so that the curve overlaps with the far left artboard (the text is always in the same spot). I will just know the green area for a given name, as well as the original coordinates for the far left image. The new image would be placed in the center of the original image, so I need to offset it to move it up and left.

It's been a long time since I've used any trigonometry. Thanks.

Comment: When you transform straight text to arc-aligned text its width and height changes and depends on position on circle. Are the height and width of the name given for straight text? You need to find right bottom corner of text frame after converting to arc-aligned?

Comment: Essentially, yes, @IvanKaznacheyeu though rather than using arc type, I am typing on a circular path.

Comment: What do you mean by "intersecting point of the text frame"? Is that the intersecting point of the two diagonals of the text box or something else?

Comment: @YNK I added an additional paragraph and image explaining the issue. Every time I place a new name in my printer software, it will be in the center of the original, fullscale frame (left image), so I need to offset it up and left.

Comment: It's complicated by the fact that the arc is not an exact 45 degree angle (more like 42 degree, toward the top), and that the arc length is 115 degrees

Comment: According to your second picture you know $w$ and $h$ for text frame with circular arc-aligned text, not for straight text. Is it correct? Or you know both?

Comment: If you know $w$ and $h$ only for text frame containing circular text, formula will be different for different cases. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2MZ5.png

Comment: For first case in my previous comment: $w=IJ=r_1\cos(\theta+\alpha)-r_2\cos(\theta-\alpha)$, $h=JK=r_2\sin(\theta+\alpha)-r_1\sin(\theta-\alpha)$, $\theta=\angle BAG$, $\alpha=\angle DAG$, $r_1=AE$, $r_2=AB$. If one knows $w$, $h$, $r_2$, $\theta$ one can solve equations to find $r_1$, $\alpha$, and then find $x_K=r_1\cos(\theta+\alpha)$, $y_K=r_1\sin(\theta-\alpha)$.

Comment: In my last comment angle $\theta=\angle BAG$ is measured clockwise, it can be 335 or 332 degrees. Angle $\alpha =\angle DAG$ is  measured counterclockwise. It has the same value as $\alpha=\angle CAG$ which is measured clockwise.

Answer (score 1):

[image: TextBoxOffset]

$$x=OD=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{4r^2-h^2-w^2}\cos\left(\phi\right)\tag{1}$$

$$y=CD=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{4r^2-h^2-w^2}\sin\left(\phi\right)\tag{2}$$

Could you please test the values given above to see whether they work for you. Of course you need to calculate the angle $\phi$ from the known value of $335^o$. You also need to find the sought offsets from the $x$ and $y$ values calculated using (1) and (2).

Comment: Apologies for the horribly late reply, but this helped me arrive at the correction solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: It is my pleasure.